# every cell of my tableview reloads when add-cell button is clicked

Tags: swift, tableview, cell, reload

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOVkn.png)
picture of two cells. the first one is with the enabled button and the filled label

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPuP1.png)
picture of the tableview after i have added 3 new files. every cell is reset

hey guys, i have created a tableview and an addButton. when i click the addButton a new custom xib Cell is loaded. Every cell has a button (checkbox button that changes the image if it is clicked). when i click the button in the cell a new String should pop up in the label in the cell. if the addButton is clicked after this process everything disappears in the cell. the label is empty again and the button is unchecked. Now i want to know how i can stop the reload for every cell if the addButton is clicked.

```swift
var sliderValues = [String]()

    @IBAction func addNewCell(_ sender: Any) {
        sliderValues.insert("\(Int(waterAmountSlider.value)) L", at: 0)
        tableView.reloadData()


    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return sliderValues.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "xibcell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell


        cell.cellButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "disabledCheckbox"),    for: UIControl.State.normal)
        cell.secondLabel.text = sliderValues[indexPath.row]
        cell.firstLabel.text = ""
        cell.firstLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Gill Sans", size: 19)
        cell.secondLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Gill Sans", size: 19)


        return cell

    }
```

Comment: Replace `tableview.reloadData()` with this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614879-insertrows

Comment: it gives me an error

Comment: Cannot convert value of type '[IndexPath].Type' to expected argument type '[IndexPath]'

Comment: Make sure you initialize it correctly `[IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)]` and don't forget to put it in an array

Answer (score 3):

You can insert a single row

```
@IBAction func addNewCell(_ sender: Any) {
    sliderValues.insert("\(Int(waterAmountSlider.value)) L", at: 0)
    tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
}
```

Side note: If reloading the entire table view changes the UI in the other cells then there’s something wrong with your design.

Comment: now i have another problem, when i scroll down in the tableview the cell are reset. so they are empty again

Comment: I know, see the side note. You are manipulating the cells without saving the state (for example the state of the checkbox) in the data model.

Comment: Use a struct rather than a simple String array as data source, update the model whenever the UI is modified and set the values of all UI elements in `cellForRow`

Comment: how should the struct look like ?

Comment: At least a String member for the slider value and additional members for all UI elements whose states can be modified.

Comment: isnt there a function to just save the current state of a cell ?

Comment: No, it isn't. You are responsible to do that.